# Get SQL data And show it in a text box?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the last few days I am trying to get data from my SQL table and get it into my textbox.

The table name : "check".

The code I am using :

```
SqlDataReader myReader = null;

connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
connection.Open();

var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [check]", connection);
myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    TextBox1.Text = myReader.ToString();
}
connection.Close();
```

I am getting nothing as a result. Anyone know why?  Maybe I am not calling the SQL correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT ColumnName FROM [check]";
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            TextBox1.Text = reader["ColumnName"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Some comments:

- don't use `*`, specify only those fields that you need
- use `using` - less code, guaranteed disposal
- I assume this is a test program, otherwise it does not make sense to reset `Text` to a in the loop

Comment: +1 for your comments - every C# database developer should follow those - always!

Answer (score 4):

```
 TextBox1.Text = myReader["fieldname"].ToString();
```

also I think you can change `while` with `if` because for every row from your table you'll overwrite textbox text!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TextBox1.AppendText(myReader["columnname"].ToString());
```

Comment: i have changed the code to :     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        
       
       
        

      
 

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT ItemNow FROM [check]";
    connection.Open();
    while (myReader.Read())
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + myReader["ItemNow"].ToString();
}
still not working :( thanks all !

Comment: @user796862. You've commented on a different answer. Anyways use AppendText as I specified.

Comment: @user796862. I don't see myReader = command.ExecuteReader(); in your last comment. Maybe this is causing issue. Anyways did you check the text present in myReader["ItemNow"].ToString() in QuickWatch? What error are you getting? Debug the code and identify the line on which you are getting error.

Comment: i am done debug, nothing happnd. its saying "All ok." no errors. but the textbox is empty. i done like this :myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT [ItemNow] FROM [check]";
    connection.Open();
    while (myReader.Read())
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text +myReader["ItemNow"].ToString();

Comment: @Alon M. You need to do this: TextBox1.AppendText(myReader["ItemNow"].ToString());
Also add the value of myReader["ItemNow"].ToString() in Watch and set a break point inside the while loop where text is appended, to check what text is being appended.

Comment: Thanks.. Its working. Ty All :).(i have done some errors in the db it self, this is the reseon it didnt work) thanks all again.