# Reading Querying database with a Parameter to Display Results in Text Boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm currently building a database font end and I'm currently stuck. I'm trying to take the List item of a datasourced drop down list and use that as a parameter in a SQL query. I then wan each column from those results to be displayed in a text box. Here's some code!

On button event:

```
protected void ButtonAsset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExecuteSelect(DropDownListAsset.Selecteditem.Text);
}
```

Getting the Connection String:

```
    public string GetConnectionStringMyConn()
{
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my_conn"].ConnectionString;
}
```

The Select method:

```
    private void ExecuteSelect(string Aname)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStringMyConn());
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "Select tblAssets.AssetID, tblAssets.Domain, tsysOS.OSname, tblAssets.SP,"
        + "tblAssets.Memory, tblAssets.Processor, tblAssetCustom.Manufacturer, tblAssetCustom.Model)"
        + "FROM tblAssets"
        + "INNER JOIN tblAssetsCustom ON tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID "
        + "INNER JOIN tsysOS ON tblAssets.OScode = tsysOS.OScode "
        + "WHERE tblAssets.AssetName = @AssetName";
        connection.Open();


        SqlParameter[] Aparam = new SqlParameter[1];
        Aparam[0] = new SqlParameter("@AssetName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        Aparam[0].Value = Aname;

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            TextBoxAssetID.Text = reader["AssetID"].ToString();
            TextBoxDomain.Text = reader["Domain"].ToString();
            TextBoxOS.Text = reader["OSname"].ToString();
            TextBoxSP.Text = reader["SP"].ToString();
            TextBoxMemory.Text = reader["Memory"].ToString();
            TextBoxProcessor.Text = reader["Processor"].ToString();
            TextBoxManufacturer.Text = reader["Manufacturer"].ToString();
            TextBoxModel.Text = reader["Model"].ToString();
        }


        connection.Close();
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I keep getting syntax errors on using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) and I cannot understand why. I've been using this [Get SQL data And show it in a text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341819/get-sql-data-and-show-it-in-a-text-box) for the reader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do Like this

```
    SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;        
    command.CommandText = "Select tblAssets.AssetID, tblAssets.Domain, tsysOS.OSname, tblAssets.SP,"
    + " tblAssets.Memory, tblAssets.Processor, tblAssetCustom.Manufacturer, tblAssetCustom.Model"
    + " FROM tblAssets"
    + " INNER JOIN tblAssetsCustom ON tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID "
    + " INNER JOIN tsysOS ON tblAssets.OScode = tsysOS.OScode "
    + " WHERE tblAssets.AssetName = @AssetName";
    connection.Open();

    command.Parameters.Add("@AssetName",SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = Aname;      

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {      
          TextBoxAssetID.Text = reader["AssetID"].ToString();
          TextBoxDomain.Text = reader["Domain"].ToString();
          TextBoxOS.Text = reader["OSname"].ToString();
          TextBoxSP.Text = reader["SP"].ToString();
          TextBoxMemory.Text = reader["Memory"].ToString();
          TextBoxProcessor.Text = reader["Processor"].ToString();
          TextBoxManufacturer.Text = reader["Manufacturer"].ToString();
          TextBoxModel.Text = reader["Model"].ToString();
        }

    ////// Rest of code goes from Here ...
```

Comment: No that just Gives me the same error sadly

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Line 56:             cmd.Parameters.Add("@AssetName",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Aname;
Line 57: 
Line 58:             using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
Line 59:             {
Line 60:                 while (reader.Read())

Comment: Check the edited answer. i have remove `)` bracket from your `command.CommandText`

Comment: Ok I've done that No longer getting an error. The text doesn't seem to be Showing, Does the fact I have the text boxes as read only affect it?

Comment: No, This won't be the issue. Check on debug did you getting any values in sqlDataReader to read

Comment: I've run the debut, there's nothing coming through it seems

Comment: Then try running this query in sqlserver, Weather it returns any row for this `assetName`

Comment: Well I've tried the query entering in one of the knows asset names and it returns an output

Comment: perhaps Its the variable being searched and not the SQL statement? The way the statement gets the parameters could be wrong?

Comment: changing the while to an If hasn't changed anything, I'm still getting The thread '<No Name>'  message from the debug

Comment: I don't think there is any issue in code here.. did compiler goes into  `if block` during debug. if yes, what you getting in `reader["AssetID"].ToString();` statement

Comment: No doesn't seem to be going into the if block, to be honest I'm pretty new to Visual studio not sure where the compiler is in the debugger

Comment: AH HA! we have it my friend! I put a break point at the end of the Select method, It took me to the Button event, It should be DropDownListAsset.SelectedItem.Text rather than DropDownListAsset.text